# Thymeleaf - Try to create a delete button for each image

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

So, i want to create a delete button for every image available. The problem is when i click the delete button, it doesnt even go to controller

Controller

```
@Autowired
private PropertyClientService propertyClientService;

@GetMapping(value = {"/property/list"})
public ModelAndView list() {
    return new ModelAndView("property/list.html");
}

@GetMapping(value = {"/property/edit/{id}"})
public String edit(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("property", propertyClientService.get(id));
    return "property/edit";
}

 @DeleteMapping(value = {"/property/deleteimage/{id}"}, params = "action=deleteImage")
public String deleteImage(
        @PathVariable Long id) {
    propertyClientService.deleteImage(id);
    return "redirect:/admin/property/list";
}
```

html with thymeleaf

```
                        <form class="form form-horizontal" name="editProperty"
                          th:action="@{/admin/property/update/}+${property.id}" th:object="${property}"
                          method="post">
                           <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                Photo:
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8" id="photo" th:each="image : *{images}">
                                <img th:src="${image.url}"/>
                                <a th:href="|@{/admin/property/deleteimage/}+${id}|" class="btn btn-danger" value="deleteImage">Delete</a>
                                <!--<button type="submit" name="action" value="deleteImage">Delete Image</button>-->
                            </div>

                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="addMoreFiles('addPhoto')" class="btn btn-default">Add
                                Photo</a>

                            <div class="col-sm-10 addPhoto">
                                <input type="file" name="addPhoto" onchange="readURL(this);"/><br/>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                    </form>
```

error

> There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
>   Request method 'GET' not supported

Im new to programming world. Please excuse if the code arent tidy or there is silly mistake or the way i ask question is bad. Please guide me with easy word, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting a ***Delete Request*** in your controller which is unsatisfied by your link :

`<a th:href="|@{/admin/property/deleteimage/}+${id}|" class="btn btn-danger" value="deleteImage">Delete</a>` which produces a GET request.

You can do two things:

1. You can change your Mapping to a GetMapping.
2. You can send your form with a JS function and while sending it you can change your method to DELETE.